# How it works with the Facebook Like Button Count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a very simple question for which i can't find an answer yet.

If a post in a website has 20 likes and / or shares should this post link have the same number of likes and / or shares in the Facebook Page (or wall) when posted in Facebook or the post link like and / or share counting would start from 0 (zero)?

And again, is there an official way to have all likes and / or shares received from the same post link reflected whenever the like and / or share button with count would appear for this post link?

Thank you all for the patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likes from a Facebook Like Plugin are not connected to any posted object on a Facebook Page. The only likes that ARE connected are the fans of the Page itself, so you can only use the Like Button with an URL to a Facebook Page and it will be the same count.

So if you post an URL from your website on a Facebook wall, it will be a separate count.